# How can I style a list <li> inline in the php code?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have [this list](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-basic) horizontally.

With **list-inline**,  I get the list to be horizontal, but it doesn't style the `<li>`. I would like then to add a class on the `li` elements but don't know in what place of the code I can add style.

```
<ul class="list-inline">
      <?php
        $cat_args['title_li'] = '';
        wp_list_categories(apply_filters('', $cat_args));?>
</ul>
```

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/93627/wp-list-categories-add-class-to-all-list-items-with-children

Comment: Based on the docs http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-lists you should not have this styling issue.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer.  the list-inline makes the ul go horizontal, but i would like to add a border on the li but i dont know how do i add the css for the li.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the grid of getbootstrap to display items horizontally

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

or you can try to use form-inline for displaying the items horizontally

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

You can style in CSS it using **Flexbox**. No need to use `.list-inline`.

Have a look at the code below:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul li {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  border-right: none !important;
}

ul li:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-group">
 <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. This is exact what i am trying, but i dont see where i can add the style for the li element on the php code: